# JS помочь переделать счетчик чисел

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется рабочий считчик, нужна помощь переделать немного.
На пример: считчик пересчитывает цифры от 0 до 2500, последнее число 4х значное, а мне необходимо что бы считчик пока считал подставлял недостающие ноли перед неполным числом, то есть 0000 -- 0025 -- 0125 -- 0725 -- 1250 -- хххх

Рабочий пример:

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
        // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

        // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
        var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
            increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

        return $(this).each(function() {
            var _this = this,
                loopCount = 0,
                value = options.from,
                interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

            function updateTimer() {
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

                if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                    options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                }

                if (loopCount >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;

                    if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                        options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
        to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
        onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
        onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: 1,
            to: 2500,
            speed: 5000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="timer"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
        // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

        // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
        var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
            increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

        return $(this).each(function() {
            var _this = this,
                loopCount = 0,
                value = options.from,
                interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

            function updateTimer() {
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals).padStart(4, '0'));

                if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                    options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                }

                if (loopCount >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;

                    if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                        options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
        to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
        onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
        onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: 1,
            to: 2500,
            speed: 5000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="timer"></span>
```

Comment: не подскажите как добавить цвет color:green для числа который считается ? ну то есть если первый 0 есть он остается красным цветом, а считаемое число, поменять на зеленое

Comment: @TileaWebsite я не понял. Если разного цвета, то их надо заворачивать в отдельные `span`-ы.